# Springboot gateway Prometheus collecting huge data

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-gateway, prometheus-java

I am using **springboot** as microservice.

I have around **20 microservices** in my k8s cluster.

I am using **promethues** to collect data to show in grafana.

In that application there are some url which uses Path variable like as follow

1. /v1/contacts/{id}
2. /v1/users/{id}

There are few more urls, If I consider all such URLs in all microservices then that could be around **60 to 70 URLs** which uses path variable.

**Problem :**

Now whenever any url is getting requested i.e like

1. /v1/contacts/10
2. /v1/contacts/111
3. /v1/contacts/51
4. /v1/users/91

so on...

Then promethus is collecting metrics for all such url. After some time it has huge metrics, and at the end my response time is increased for collecting data from prometheus.

So basically I want to clear prometheus logs after some interval from my springboot application.

I am not sure whether its possible or not.

Can someone please help me to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you consider sending http post requests like this https://www.robustperception.io/deleting-time-series-from-prometheus from spring boot? Or maybe a better solution would be filter undesired metrics at the prometheus scrape time?

Comment: @Felipe this is like deleting prometheus data from prometheus server, My problem is /actuator/promethes endpoint into sprintboot application. Prometheus data is stored into springboot application and because of that it hits performance.

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus has several flags that configure local storage.

`--storage.tsdb.path`: Where Prometheus writes its database. Defaults to `data/`.
`--storage.tsdb.retention.time`: When to remove old data. Defaults to 15d. Overrides storage.tsdb.retention if this flag is set to anything other than default.
`--storage.tsdb.retention.size`: [EXPERIMENTAL] The maximum number of bytes of storage blocks to retain. The oldest data will be removed first. Defaults to 0 or disabled. This flag is experimental and may change in future releases. Units supported: B, KB, MB, GB, TB, PB, EB. Ex: "512MB"

Prometheus storage [link](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/)

Steps:

1. Spring Boot application exposure monitoring indicators, add the
   following dependencies. 
   `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>`
    or

    `<groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>`
   `artifactId>simpleclient_spring_boot</artifactId>`
2. Prometheus collects Spring Boot indicator data. First, get the
   Docker image of Prometheus: `docker pull prom/prometheus`

   Then, write the configuration file prometheus.yml:

   ```
   global:
     scrape_interval: 10s
     scrape_timeout: 10s
     evaluation_interval: 10m

   scrape_configs:
     - job_name: prometheus
       scrape_interval: 5s
       scrape_timeout: 5s
       metrics_path: /metrics
       scheme: http
   ```

   You can add more values to it. Sample [here](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/release-2.19/config/testdata/conf.good.yml)
3. Next, start Prometheus:

   ```
   docker run -d -p 9090:9090 \
   -u root \
   -v /opt/prometheus/tsdb:/etc/prometheus/tsdb \
   -v /opt/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
   --privileged=true prom/prometheus \
   --storage.tsdb.path=/etc/prometheus/tsdb \
   --storage.tsdb.retention.time=7d \
   --storage.tsdb.retention.size = 300MB \
   --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
   ```

Alternative way, you can use this link [Monitoring Spring Boot projects with Prometheus](https://keepgrowing.in/tools/monitoring-spring-boot-projects-with-prometheus/) 
But make sure when you run the Prometheus server with Docker Compose you have to update the `commands` section with size or time properties.

Comment: My problem is not to remove data from prometheus server, **But** the problem is my sprintboot is collecting prometheus data and keep it into JVM memory, and because of that when next time I hit prometheus endpont /actuator/prometheus then it is taking huge time. I am already clearing data from prometheus server.

Comment: Prometheus usually consumes lot of memory when data is huge. A bug : https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/1881 . Spring boot doesn't direclty provides support . Either you  can limit the number of samples per individual scrape or modify the query through range selectors. Few useful links , for memory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56115912/why-does-prometheus-consume-so-much-memory . For tweaking memory https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/1.8/storage/#memory-usage  . Query modifications https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#range-vector-selectors